# how to create pulse sound wave in iOS

Tags: ios, wave, pulse

I found how to create sine wave or square wave , but I can't modify to create a pulse wave in objective-c

this code creates sine wave but I need to create pulse waves.

```
OSStatus RenderTone(
void *inRefCon, 
AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags, 
const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp, 
UInt32                      inBusNumber, 
UInt32                      inNumberFrames, 
AudioBufferList             *ioData)
{
// Fixed amplitude is good enough for our purposes
const double amplitude = 0.25;

// Get the tone parameters out of the view controller
ToneGeneratorViewController *viewController =
    (ToneGeneratorViewController *)inRefCon;
double theta = viewController->theta;
double theta_increment = 2.0 * M_PI * viewController->frequency / viewController->sampleRate;

// This is a mono tone generator so we only need the first buffer
const int channel = 0;
Float32 *buffer = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[channel].mData;

 // Generate the samples
 for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++) 
{
    buffer[frame] = sin(theta) * amplitude;

    theta += theta_increment;
    if (theta > 2.0 * M_PI)
    {
         theta -= 2.0 * M_PI;
    } 
}

// Store the theta back in the view controller
viewController->theta = theta;

return noErr;
 }
```

I need to modify this code to create pulse waves

this is what exactly I want to create
[Pulse wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave)
[image: pulse wave]

Comment: do you know what `theta` stands for in the code?